# How to set data-attribute between image's src and alt attributes?

Tags: simple-html-dom

Order:

```
$img->src = 'someimage.webp';
$img->alt = null;
$img->{'data-ext'} = 'png';
$img->alt = 'somealt';
```

Result:

```
<img src="someimage.webp" alt="somealt" data-ext="png">
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
<img src="someimage.webp" data-ext="png" alt="somealt">
```

**UPD**
I found ugly solution, but this returns valid html

```
$img->src = 'someimage.webp" data-ext="png';
$img->alt = 'somealt';
```

Comment: Why do you first set alt to null? I think it will work if you omit `$img->alt = null;`

Comment: No it won't. I did this only to show that even if the attribute already existed and we force it to be deleted, then add a new one, nothing will still work

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data-attribute to be between src and alt and setting the alt to null  in between, one option could be to `getAllAttributes()` and use [krsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) to sort the array keys in reverse order.

For example

```
$img->src = 'someimage.webp';
$img->alt = null;
$img->{'data-ext'} = 'png';
$img->alt = 'somealt';

$attrs = $img->getAllAttributes();
krsort($attrs);
$img->attr = $attrs;

echo $img->outertext();
```

Output

```
<img src="someimage.webp" data-ext="png" alt="somealt">
```